# adding 5 to the $i after inserting the $i

Tags: php, insert

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 $db=mysql_select_db("test");
 $i=1;
 $r=" INSERT INTO test1 (score) VALUES ('$i') "  ;
 $t=mysql_query($r);
 if($t){ 
  $i=$i+5;
  echo  "done"; 
 } else { 
   echo "not done"; 
 }
?>
```

I am writing a very simple program but I am new in the php world so I am not able to find the logic . . I have defined the $i value ie 1 and I want to insert the value into the database

When the user again refreshes the page , $i value should add 5 and then insert the value . please can anybody tel me how it will b done ??

Comment: You don't need brackets here `$r=" INSERT INTO test1 (score) VALUES ('$i') ";`. Also mysql_* extension is deprecated use mysqli_* or PDO instead.

Comment: You'd have to store number of refreshes in `$_SESSION` and increment `$i` based on that. Be vary of passing data from `$_SESSION` directly to MySQL, as these come from the client and need to be sanitized.

Comment: @PawelJ.Wal please can u explain me how to do this ?? coz i have very little knowledge of php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the trick I think:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db=mysql_select_db("test");
    if(isset($_SESSION['counter']))
    {
        $i=$_SESSION['counter'];
    }
    else
    {
        $i=1;
    }
    $r=(" INSERT INTO test1 (score) VALUES ('$i') " ) ;
    $t=mysql_query($r);
    if($t)
    { 
    $i=$i+5;
    echo  "done"; }
    else
    { echo "not done"; }
    $_SESSION['counter']=$i;
?>
```

Basically, you can store data inside a session variable, which is maintained on the server and maintains, well a session, with the client/user. You can then refer to it in following pages.

Comment: Don't pass values coming from `$_SESSION` directly into `mysql_query`, that's asking for trouble. Also, you never actually _write_ into `$_SESSION`, so this code will not work.

Comment: @PawelJ.Wal Yeah, it is bad form to do so, but the OP isn't asking for a lecture on SQL Injection and changing to PDO from depracated mysql_* functions. The guy is starting out, give him some slack :)

Comment: @PawelJ.Wal I edited a few seconds after I posted it to write back to the session.

Answer (score 0):

It is fundamental to understand that PHP remembers nothing between page visits unless you store the value somewhere.  As is being said, use a SESSION value, or put it in a user Cookie, or write the value to a text file, or put it in a database.

SESSION is the best if you only want the value to be remembered for a short while (like half an hour).

In a Cookie, the user can refuse to accept it, or delete it, even accidentally.

To keep the value for longer you need to store it more permanently (in a file, in a database) - PLUS you now have the problem of identifying which user the value belonged to.

You need to take each of these options in turn, play around with them and then you will start to identify which would suit a given situation.

You will also start to learn a lot about PHP, and how your OS works.

Good luck!